# Craftercms: crafter-search sends multi-value date for repeat group with a single value date field

Tags: solr, content-management-system

If you index a repeat group with date fields (xyz_dt), crafter-search will group those dates into a range then sent to Solr. Solr complains xyz_dt is a single value field not multi-value:

```
Apr 21, 2017 7:21:03 AM org.apache.solr.common.SolrException log
SEVERE: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: ERROR: [doc=livepublish:/site/components/roadmap/social-responsibility.xml] multiple values encountered for non multiValued field items.item.expiration_dt: [2015-11-19T05:00:00.000Z, 2015-11-24T05:00:00.000Z]
```

Has this bug been fixed and since what version?

Comment: It would be helpful to state which versions of Solr and Crafter you are using.. especially for future users who find your question from searches.

Comment: It's a Crafter 2.3.6 in production. I was told that this bug is fixed in later version. I want to know which version or the bug number.